# Science related rebus wordplay, what is it?

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, rebus, science

[image: rebus]
Can anyone figure out what this rebus wordplay is? Doing a Google search will help you a lot, and is recommended, but reverse image search would be doing basically all the detective work for you, so don't do that. It's easier to figure out if done from left to right and then re-examined as a whole.

It's two things, one of which is an example of the other.

Hint 1:

> every element in that image is useful in finding the final answer; also, subtle things like relative sizes of the elements and also visual/physical interpretations of the objects(s) in the image can be of help to finding the final answer, but are not necessarily required.

Hint 2:

> Some of the elements in the images are extremely specific things and not general stock images representing the word, but I will not say which ones those are. (if you check the comments I did reveal one)

Hint 3:

> It's a chemical compound. (sorry for lack of originality but chemical compounds are great for rebuses!)

EDIT: Look at the comments on Bass's answer below for more hints, clarifications and confirmations.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :) Please [take a tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @Rubio Reverse image search is not the answer to this at all, it's just a bad habit for these kinds of puzzles because it's essentially cheating. I asked not to use reverse image search because there is one obscure element in the image that can be figured out through a subtle hint that would be useless if you were to just reverse image that element somehow.  The puzzle is entirely 100% original and the idea and design are all mine. It's a chemistry related concept as I said before (concept, compound, reaction, etc but I won't say exactly what)

Comment: @Rubio i can vouch that this is original. I waoted for about an hour for him to finish making it

Comment: On a scale from one to Ethyl-5-amino-1H-pyrazole-4-carboxylate, how likely is it that I have heard the name of this particular chemical compound before?

Comment: @Bass unlikely because it is obscure and useless I believe. but it’s not ridiculously long or complicated though is long.

Comment: Is the specific song on the sheet music important? @diobuceulb

Comment: @MicCrozier yes extremely important

Comment: @MicCrozier We may be in trouble, since the music is a generic drum beat that could be from any of a hundred different songs. If I had to guess from the particular rhythm of the beat, maybe from late eighties or early nineties?

Comment: @MicCrozier [Cupid's dead](https://open.spotify.com/track/571rcJUOJ5d8QLrc500nW3?si=jIomNl98SM2KDV7zaKOonw) by Extreme is the closest I could get to a song that begins with a drum beat like that. It's just a little slower than 136 bpm, and it's not exactly the same beat, but all the rhythmic elements are there, so if you can think of a piece with a similar sounding drum line, that may very well be it.

Comment: @Bass you're getting really close!!! hint: it's not "a" song but it's used in lots and lots of songs all the time. your first comment from 50 minutes ago was on the right track. that's the last hint i can give for that before it just becomes super obvious. (if it's not already super obvious)

Comment: I added two tags for you @diobuceulb. "Knowledge tag" was added since you recommended the use of a computer, and thats what a knowledge tag is for.

Comment: @North Not really - the [tag:computer-puzzle] tag is probably better than [tag:knowledge], at least if we don't know exactly how the computer needs to be used.

Comment: Is this an organic or inorganic compound?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert inorganic

Comment: The whole compound or just the ion?

Comment: @diobuceulb, I think that I have it down to three, but I'm still not sure how the reversed complex plane fits in

Comment: added answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting my account so here it is

> it's amen break not break pentacle ore OCUP rate tu ion, on complex coordinates backwards (coordination complex)

or

> **amminepentachlorocuprate (II) ion which is a coordination complex**

the hint to find OCUP was to see that the foreground object is a rocket and if you do a database search of rocket related terms with the word "cup" which is what it looks like, "apollo cup" will bring up the search result for the product webpage of something called OCUP." pretty lame hint but there were other ways to find it too, just a bit too obscure to be easy to do.

thanks everyone for trying this rebus and i'm glad you all got as far as you did with it.

Comment: Drats, I had the entire name, just wasn't sure how the background fit in. If you had just said ion specifically, I would've been able to answer it right away.

Answer (score 7):

Since the answer is an unfamiliar chemical compound, I don't think any of us can manage this alone, so I started this wiki answer for collaboration. If you want to post a separate answer yourself, please feel free to do so.

Here's the blue band split to pieces to keep ideas (I prefixed mine with my name, but feel free to edit or remove them if you need to) and given hints from comments (in blockquotes) in better order.

---

[image]

### Amen

> hint: it's not "a" song but it's used in lots and lots of songs all the time. your first comment from 50 minutes ago (EDIT: included below) was on the right track.
>
> ..the music is a generic drum beat that could be from any of a hundred different songs. If I had to guess from the particular rhythm of the beat, maybe from late eighties or early nineties?

Bass: the music seems to be a Funk / Soul / Hiphop -type drum beat, quickish and a bit "bouncy". The picture crossed out with the blue symbol seems to be of a broken glass.

North: The first image is something known as an "Amen Break"

---

[image]

## Pentacle

Bass: Medal?

North: I was thinking the second image is a star amulet?

Peregrine Lennert: It looks like a pentagram, so maybe something to do with *penta*-. **Update**: Sorry for doing this late but wanted to post my own answer first. It's "pentacle"

> Be more specific of what kind of medal like object it is, but it's not really a medal, no
>
> penta is close but its not an prefix it's an entire word

---

[image]

### Ore

Bass: Hard to tell with so few pixels, but looks like a rock, probably metallic, or possibly molten on one side. Maybe "ore" or "meteorite"? Might be just a lump of some metal too, though.

---

[image]

Bass: Never seen one of these. A water filter? A centrifuge?

Peregrine Lennert: The fourth image appears to be a humidifier, dehumidifier, or maybe an air conditioner. Zooming in, one can see the word *cool* on the tag. Searching for the specific product in the image doesn't turn up anything useful, so I'm adding my contribution here.

> this is the one that requires the subtle visual interpretation of the entire object on the complex plane to help you figure out. It's a very specific product and that hint will help you find it slightly better. you can save it for later.
>
> Q: How am I on the fourth?
>   A: getting colder. think smaller also, liquids. hope that helps narrow it down.
>
> it does not say cool on the tag. another hint is that the word on the tag probably won't help you figure out what it is. though here is a hint: if you figure out what the entire object in the foreground containing all the elements can be interpreted as being, combined with my last comment in reply to you, I can then tell you how to use that information to help you figure out what it is.

---

[image]

### Rate

Bass: Maybe "rate" or "slope"?

---

[image]

### Tu

Bass: Seems to be a stereotypical French guy pointing at me. Maybe some pronoun in French? Like "Tu"?

---

[image]

### Ion

Bass: again hard to tell, but it's either a light, or high speed burning gas. Possibly "-lite", or the name of the gas, since we are going for a chemical compound.

Peregrine Lennert: It looks like the exhaust from a jet engine, or something similar.

F1Krazy: I'm pretty sure this is a Hall-effect thruster, also known as an ion thruster. Since we're looking for a chemical compound, the important word here is probably "ion".

> Seventh object: you're getting a bit colder. the name for this one includes the entire object and not just the gas/emittance part.
>
> Extra hint: the seventh object at the end is what will help you figure out the tiny extra hint to help you find the name of the fourth object.

---

### Background:

Bass: Seems to be the complex plane, mirrored horizontally.

---

### Full answer:

> Q: how likely is it that I have heard the name of this particular chemical compound before? –
>
> A: unlikely because it is obscure and useless I believe. but it’s not ridiculously long or complicated though is long.
>
> global hint: knowing how the reversed complex plane and everything plays into the other word of the rebus is also important but will not help you find the name of the chemical compound (unless you use that information to narrow it down a bit if you have knowledge of chemistry.) [this is actually a really big hint (but not for the objects in the foreground) if you interpret it properly]

---

Comment: First object: you're getting close just need to combine and refine those 2 objects to get the word. but you're getting too general now, it's not an adjective. (no more hints for this first object because it has gotten too many)

Comment: Second object: Be more specific of what kind of medal like object it is, but it's not really a medal, no.

Comment: Third object: Ore is correct

Comment: Fourth object: this is the one that requires the subtle visual interpretation of the entire object on the complex plane to help you figure out. It's a very specific product and that hint will help you find it slightly better. you can save it for later.

Comment: Fifth object: rate is correct

Comment: Sixth object: Tu is correct!!!

Comment: Seventh object: you're getting a bit colder. the name for this one includes the entire object and not just the gas/emittance part.

Comment: Extra hint: the seventh object at the end is what will help you figure out the tiny extra hint to help you find the name of the fourth object.

Comment: global hint: knowing how the reversed complex plane and everything plays into the other word of the rebus is also important but will not help you find the name of the chemical compound (unless you use that information to narrow it down a bit if you have knowledge of chemistry.) [this is actually a really big hint (but not for the objects in the foreground) if you interpret it properly]

Comment: Added some potential help

Comment: So have I. Assuming I'm right, that just leaves the fourth image...

Comment: @F1Krazy ion is correct (this last one doesn't include the rest of the word [thruster] but the fact that it's a thruster will help for one of the other images)

Comment: @PeregrineLennert penta is close but its not an prefix it's an entire word

Comment: @diobuceulb, How am I on the fourth?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert getting colder. think smaller also, liquids. hope that helps narrow it down.

Comment: @diobuceulb So not as big as any of those, it does narrow it down slightly. Am I right in it reading cool?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert it does not say cool on the tag. another hint is that the word on the tag probably won't help you figure out what it is. though here is a hint: if you figure out what the entire object in the foreground containing all the elements can be interpreted as being, combined with my last comment in reply to you, I can then tell you how to use that information to help you figure out what it is.

Comment: @diobuceulb Having a bit of difficulty with the end of the name of the object, #4 is what has me stuck

Comment: @diobuceulb, if you truly think that what's on the tag won't help me figure it out, then what is on the tag?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert I think it says "tea" plus some kind of symbol but i'm not sure. it's not relevant though i don't think because i already did a few tests on how to find it based on a hint that i will be revealing once you figure out what the foreground object is supposed to be and it works fine if you do a google search (leads you right to it). so don't get misled by it saying tea too much by overthinking it is some tea drinking device (not going to say if it isn't either lol)

Comment: Is it "pendant" for that medal thing?

Comment: @NikhilEshvar No

Comment: Searching for "blue pentagram amulet" shows the amulet for #2. It also says like "Pewter Pendant"... So yeah...

Comment: #2 "Pentacle" maybe? :)

Comment: @NikhilEshvar ah, cool, so we get "amen-pentacle-ore-something" which sounds like amino-penta-chloro-something"

Comment: @Bass I have had that since yesterday, sorry for not posting, but can't figure #4 out on my own. See my answer for what I have had since yesterday but was trying to complete before posting.

Comment: I've added a oartial answer, @diobuceulb

Comment: Is this chemical compound one word by the way

Comment: Perhaps #4 image should be [flipped](https://imgur.com/EUsWSqo)?!? That also forms like a word I guess... :D

Comment: @diobuceulb what's the final hint?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert final hint: observe the image in the foreground is a rocket. now think of rocket related terms (spacecraft, nasa, astronauts, etc) and combine that with what you think the 4th object is and search google for it. if you get both the type of object and the spacecraft related term correct it will appear in the search results but it is not the actual name of the product, the name will be in the title of the search result and the hint you found will be in the url.

Comment: @diobuceulb, sorry, but I thought that there was a hint about how the background ties in with the answer

Comment: @PeregrineLennert oh, well *shrugs*. the background tying to the answer will become obvious once you find the answer.

Comment: @diobuceulb Directly giving the final piece of the answer, or for checking the final answer? Also, is it at the front or the back?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert neither, they're not dependent on each other but one is an example of the other.

Answer (score 1):

This math rebus... is it:

> a reverse complex plane?

Because the larger object is the reverse of a

> complex plane, with I in it.

Can’t make heads or tails of the arrow yet. Something to do with resonance frequencies, rocks, and home devices?

Comment: nope the rebus is not mathematics related at all. it’s to do with mainly chemistry but i don’t want to give more information than that. also it is not technical at all so don’t overthink it. the elements in the image are related to their words only not their concepts or mathematical behaviour.

Comment: @diobuceulb umm out of all of this I see physics, I see math (derivatives, complex plane), I see rocks, what the **** is chemistry? I’m a chemistry nerd and I don’t see chemistry yet.

Comment: it's a chemistry rebus because the answer is a chemistry related term, what part of that do you not understand? the elements in the rebus don't have to all also be related to the thing the answer is related to.

Answer (score 1):

My (very) partial answer:

> (whatever the reversed complex plain is) aminepentachlor(possibly an o here)(#4)ra(might be an e and/or a space here)tu ion (or something along these lines

Reasoning:

> We don't know the meaning of the background yet, so I'm not sure where it goes. The first one is Amen, as it is an "Amen Break" with no break signified by the broken glass being crossed out. The closest chemical term I can think of is amine or amino (Found by North). The second object is a pentacle (Found by me). The third is a picture of ore (Found by Bass). Combining the last two gets us "pentachlor" signifying a compound/ion with 5 chlorines. I am not sure how #4 fits in here, maybe it is an anion I am unsure) Fifth is "Rate" (Found by Bass). Sixth is Tu (found by Bass), unsure how it fits in). Seventh is "Ion" (found by F1Krazy).

Comment: you're really close! you just need to figure out #4 and it will all make sense including the background. also see my comment the other answer above.

Comment: @diobuceulb, is the way the background plays into the answer a hint using what a complex plane is used for in chemistry and referring to a paper on the answer?

Comment: nope, try to find out different words for a complex plane. it's all rebus/wordplay based

Answer (score 1):

## Crazy answer hints: (Hopefully might help someone)

> <s>#1: **2-amino** (2 and amen) or 1-amino (the circle points to the +1) 
>
>  #2: **1-penta** (By graph it's in 1 therefore pentacle+1) 
>
>  #3: **1-ore** (1+ore)
>
>  #4: ?!? 
>
>  #5: **forate**?!? (4 in graph and rate => 4-rate)  
>
>  #6: **5-tu** (5 in graph and tu) 
> #7: **3-ion** (-2i=-6 => i=3)</s>

## Hint and findings based on comment:

> #1: **amine** (amen) 
>  #2: **pentachl** (pentacle) 
>  #3: **or** (ore) 
>  #4: ?!? (beginning with o maybe for chloro...) 
>  #5: **rate** (rate) 
>  #6: **tu** (tu) 
>  #7: **ion** (ion) 
>  **Findings:** #6+#7 could be considered as **T**+**Io** which leads to **TiO** which is Titanium Oxide. So maybe we find chemical names and abbreviations too?!?

## Answer attempt 1:

> ***[Penta-1,4-dien-3-one, 1-amino-1-trifluoromethyl-5-(4-methoxyphenyl)-](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.725016.html)*** ? This is the first thing that came when I searched vaguely

Comment: close but there is not number association in the rebus therefore there are no numbers in the compound name. the rest are correct but it's not amino it's amine. furthermore the words in the rebus are almost identical to the final word. for example amen ---> amine not amino which includes the extra o sound.

Answer (score 1):

**PARTIAL ANSWER!!!**.
I hope this is helpful, I just realized this.

> The reverse complex plane tells us to read the compound BACKWARDS, since its reverse. In addition, AMINE is a suffix word, or comes at thee END of a word, rather than amino- the prefix version. The OP has confirmed that the word is amine.

So actually what we have is

> Tu-ion-Ra(te?)-(?fourth word perhaps cation or anion)-pentachlor-amine.

Comment: Ion would come before tu

Comment: or-pentacl-amine not pentachlor-amine, due to reversing the name

Comment: Not everything has to be flipped though.

Comment: Possibly, but I feel that if it was reversed, the objects would be in that order.

Comment: nope this is wrong. if i were to give a hint it would be don't overthink the background lol.